# How to use onload inside form input?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function:

```
function loadDefaultDate(){

    var currentDate = new Date();
    var curYear, curMonth, curDay;

    curYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    curMonth = ("0" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    curDay = ("0" + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2);

    document.getElementById("startDate").value = curYear + "-" + curMonth + "-" + curDay;


}
```

And html form input:

```
<input type=text name="startDate" size=10 maxlength=10 onload="loadDefaultDate()" onclick="javascript:resetValues();">
```

Why I am not getting default date when page loads?

Comment: Try object.addEventListener("load", loadDefaultDate());
The documentation says Supported HTML tags:  <body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>

Comment: An input has no `onload` event, there's nothing to load? Only images, iframes, the body, the window etc. that has content that is loaded, has an `onload` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try with this:

  function load() {
    console.log("load event detected!");
  }
  window.onload = load;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input has `name="startDate"`, but you are trying to look it up by Id.

Set the proper Id on your input.

```
<input type=text name="startDate" id="startDate" size=10 maxlength=10  onclick="javascript:resetValues();">
```

I also manually called `loadDefaultDate` in javascript. As adeneo's comment mentions, `onload` does not work with `input` elements.

```
function loadDefaultDate(){
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var curYear, curMonth, curDay;

    curYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    curMonth = ("0" + (currentDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    curDay = ("0" + currentDate.getDate()).slice(-2);

    document.getElementById("startDate").value = curYear + "-" + curMonth + "-" + curDay;
}

loadDefaultDate();
```

Comment: You were right, silly me that I didn't add id, but as you mentioned it turned out that html doesn't have onload, Jorge Mejia's answer was on point. Thanks for pointing out my mistake!